# gsutil cp command error, CommandException: NO URLs matched:

Tags: cmd, cp, gsutil

Good day, I am not a developer but running simple `gsutil` command to manage my *google cloud storage*.

I ran into an issue where I run the following command form the cmd

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs:/bucket/ .
```

Scenario1: with most buckets this goes just fine

Scenario2: there is one bucket where I get an error and I really have no clue how this is possible

the error I get is:

> CommandException: NO URLs matched: gs://content-music.tapgamez.com/

I am hoping anyone can share their thoughts with me

thnx

Answer (score 1):

One scenario where this error message appears is when the bucket you're attempting to recursively copy from contains no objects, e.g.:

```
$ gsutil mb gs://some-random-bucket-name
$ gsutil -m cp -r gs://some-random-bucket-name/ .
CommandException: No URLs matched: gs://some-random-bucket-name/
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
```

The same issue, but for the `rm` command, is being tracked on GitHub:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/417

Answer (score 0):

`gsutil` command `rsync` doesn't seem to have this issue (working fine even on empty buckets). Try it to see if it will do that you need.
[Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync)

```
gsutil rsync -r gs://mybucket1 gs://mybucket2
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue, I was doing the following mistake -

Mistake -
`gsutil cp -r gs://<bucket-name>/src/main/resources/output/20220430 .`

Correct -
`gsutil cp -r gs://<bucket-name>//src/main/resources/output/20220430 .`

I was missing the extra '/' after bucket name.

to get the exact name , you can select the object and get that URL from there.

[image]