# Cloud Build fails to upload artifact

Tags: google-cloud-build

I have a Cloud Build, where after the last container, I try to upload Artifacts.

My yaml ends with:

```
- name: eu.gcr.io/foo/bar
  args: ["arg1"]
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: "gs://foo-bar/go/"
    paths: ["/output/*"]
```

My expectation would be that similar to CloudBuild examples, it would take the `/output` directory of the last Container and upload all its files to `foo-bar/go`. The wildcard is important to keep, though since I do not know beforehand, which files will be in `/output`.

Instead I get the error messages:

```
ERROR: could not upload /output/* to gs://foo-bar/go/; err = exit status 1
ERROR
CommandException: 1 file/object could not be transferred.
CommandException: No URLs matched: /output/*
/output/*: Uploading path....
Artifacts will be uploaded to gs://foo-bar using gsutil cp
```

Anyone got any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47885197/297331

Comment: Possible duplicate of [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52828977/can-google-cloud-build-recurse-through-directories-of-artifacts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working with an explicit *gsutil* call using a *volume*.
At this point I can just assume that some part of the examples in the docs do not actually work. This does for me, though:

```
- name: eu.gcr.io/foo/bar
  args: ["arg1"]
  volumes:
  - name: data
    path: /output
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil
  args: ["cp", "/output/*", "gs://foo-bar/go/"]
  volumes:
  - name: data
    path: /output
```

Not as slick as `artifacts` but at least it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

2 years late but I have the answer to this problem.

I came across this when I had issue. Trying to get an artifact on a bucket kept resulting in `No URLs matched`.

The problem is that the outputs folder is not persisted without the volume you created. Cloud Build does persist a folder between steps by default, this is the `/workspace` folder. If you set up your `eu.gcr.io/foo/bar` container to output to the `/workspace` folder, the following will store the artifact.

```
- name: eu.gcr.io/foo/bar
  args: ["arg1"]
artifacts:
  objects:
    location: "gs://foo-bar/go/"
    paths: ["/output/*"]
```

Within the yaml, there is also the option `dir` which lets you set a working directory. There is more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema). I have not looked into this very much but might provide a simpler solution.

Answer (score -2):

I would say that the correct approach is to have certainty of what is at the “/output” folder, so before trying to store the data you could attempt to list the folders one step before the artifacts one. Or also find for the output folder with the command “find”. You can use as a guideline this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps#example_executing_a_shell_script_from_your_source) where scripts are executed using as entry point “bash”

Comment: I did all that. Using e.g. `ls` shows exactly the 2 files I would expect.

Comment: I'd go for the option than abergmeiner has suggested, I'll make some test over that solution and comment later this week. :-)